# Add sublabel or hover text to Custom Option

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I need to give the customer aditional information regarding the custom option. How can I add a hover text (to the label) or add a sublabel (additional text) under the label title of the custom option?

Answer (score 0):

Magento can't do that out of the box.

What about adding it to CSS with `:hover:before` and `:hover:after`?

The alternative is:

- changing custom option table(s) (because of translation)
- changing form in backend
- changing controller to save everything
- changing Template in frontend to show it
- add still some CSS to style it

Comment: Where is Template file for custom options?

Comment: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml`